what is a cycle in a directed graph, and does the strong definition implies the weak one?
I have a directed graph which is strongly connected, i.e. from any node you can reach any other following directed edges.
There is this weak definition of cycles: a sequence of edges (i1,i2), (i2,i3), ...,(in,i1) where the first and last node coincide.
There is a stronger one (not sure what is called, say Eulerian?), which imposes that every node is traversed only once, i.e. does not allow for (i1,i2),(i2,i3),(i3,i4),(i4,i2),(i2,i6),(i,6,i1).
I am almost sure (?) that if a node i is in a weak cycle, i must also be in at least one eulerian cycle, but I cannot articulate this clearly. Is there a name for both notions of cycles and a simple argument to argue that the Eulerian cycle must exists if there is a weak cycle?

Typical (weak) definition of a cycle is that the first and last node coincide.

sorry, typo, you're right

I would call the first object a "closed walk" and the second object a "cycle". ("Eulerian" means something different entirely.) Some people call the first object a "cycle" and the second object a "simple cycle", but their terminology is bad and my terminology is good.

Thanks! do you know the relationship between closed walks and cycles?

@MishaLavrov Although I agree with your choice here, I'll note for OP's sake that the word "cycle" is somewhat overloaded. The first object is a cycle (in homology theory, and even homotopy theory), and not a cycle in the sense of periodic functions or the Tour de France, etc.

@fox Draw your disallowed walk without any edge-crossings.  Can you see the cycle you want?  Which node plays a key role?  The typical proof only requires putting this observation in the correct context (hint: the cycle you want in your example is shorter than the original walk)

@brian. the key node i suppose is the one that appears several times. I thought an argument is to keep only the last time it appears. it would eventually lead back to i1. and this should be a simple/Eulerian cycle itself. But I am not an expert and might be wrong.

Yes, @fox.  That is the gist of a proof. You can formalize by induction on the length of a cycle.  If a node is met more than once, you can skip to the last time it appears and shorten the cycle accordingly.

appreciate it, does the logic holds whenever there is more than one node that appears several times? I actually don't think it does...

Suppose the vertex $v$ is on a weak cycle (usually called closed walk as noted in the comments), let $vx_1x_2\cdots x_nv$ be of minimal lenght, we'll show this is a strong cycle (usually called directed cycle). Notice that each $x_i\neq v$ otherwise, if $x_i=v$ for some $i$, $vx_1\cdots x_{i-1}x_i$ would be a shorter walk. Now, suppose $x_i=x_j$ for some $i< j$, then the walk $vx_1\cdots x_ix_{j+1}\cdots x_n v$ would be a shorter closed walk. Therefore all the vertices of the walk are distinct, except for $v$ itself
